# Where are the UIKit headers?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, header-files

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

In this directory I can find every framework except UIKit. I know I can inspect it through the help documentation but I need the files themselves this time. Does anybody knows where are they? I have the latest Xcode on Lion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my install it's /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/.

I did this by command-clicking on `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` to open UIKit.h in the editor, then right clicking in the editor and selecting "Show In Finder".

Hope that helps.

By the way, you will end up with a slightly different SDK depending on your target. There is a iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk, iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk, and so on.

Comment: It is there indeed, thank you. They didn't updated the documentation seems.